# Symfony2: Handling multiple ORM relationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to create relationships for my entities, whereby I have the following scenario:

Entity A - OneToMany relationship with Entity B
Entity B - OneToMany relationship with Entity C

When doing a 'find' on Entity A, ORM automatically queries for all matching Entity B rows. What isn't clear to me is whether ORM would automatically query for all matching Entity C rows.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$project = $em->getRepository('MyAppMainBundle:Project')->find($id);
$client = $project->getClient();
$clientProjects = $client->getClientProjects();
```

If this scenario is possible, what is best practice to implement it?

Thanks,

JB

---

**UPDATE**

I actually figured out how to do this with the mapping relationships. Key is setting up the mapping in the entities, so that Entity B properly maps in turn to Entities C. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map the relationships properly and you'll be set. It looks like you want a OneToMany/ManyToOne.

Comment: Yup, what I figured I needed to do. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the issue:

```
Parent Entity 'Client':

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientProject", mappedBy="client")
 */
private $clientProjects;
```

Child Entity 'ClientProject':

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="ClientProject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $client;
```

The controller can then use the following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$project = $em->getRepository('MyAppMainBundle:Project')->find($id);
$client = $project->getClient();
$clientProjects = $client->getClientProjects();

foreach ($clientProjects as $clientProject) {
    echo $clientProject->getSomeProperty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want all Entities to be fetched in a single request it is better to create custom repository class and use QueryBuilder to make a query where A joins B joins C. In other case the result will depend on LAZY_FETCH options, AFAIR

Comment: I appreciate the input, Ziumin! While this certainly can be done by creating a custom method in the repository class, the goal was to use ORM's built-in functionality to set this up. I figured it out after digging a bit more and it seems to be working.